# Simple ajax doesn't work in ASP.NET MVC Core 2

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this C# code:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Route("home/salam")]
        public JsonResult salam()
        {
            return new JsonResult("Alo Alo");
        }
    }
```

In my Index.cshtml I have this:

```
`
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="ppp">ppopyyyppyoptyphiopy</div>
    <div id="matn"></div>
    <script>
        $("#ppp").click(function () {
        alert("I'm Here");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/home/salam',
                dataType:"jsonp",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hello Dear");
                }
            });
    </script>
`
```

It compiles fine, but ajax doesn't work. Please help me. What should I do? The message "I'm here" appears but "Hello Dear" doesn't.

Comment: did you try change dataType:"jsonp" to dataType:"json" ?

Comment: did you check your console , any error shown there?

Comment: Thank you. I changed "jsonp" to "json". I also forgot to close the main function by a "});"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function is open, close it

```
function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/home/salam',
                dataType:"jsonp",
                success: function () {
                    alert("Hello Dear");
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> ```
> dataType:"jsonp",
> ```

But your server side code says:

> ```
> return new JsonResult("Alo Alo");
> ```

JSON and JSONP are **very different**.

The success function doesn't fire because it errors when it gets the wrong data type in the response.